# asp.net web service error on production and not locally

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

Hope i am posting in the right area!

I have an asp.net/vb web service, built in VS2012.  The project is running locally under .net 4.0 but the project was created to use .net 2.0 as that is what the production server runs.

The web service runs fine locally, but on the production server, I get an error (i hope the formatting works):-

```
BC30068: Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.
```

This is my function and properties:-

```
Public Class JobData
    Private m_ID As Integer
    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_ID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_ID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_MAID As Integer
    Public Property MAID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_MAID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_MAID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_DateAdded As DateTime
    Public Property DateAdded() As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_DateAdded
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            m_DateAdded = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_ClientID As Integer
    Public Property ClientID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_ClientID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_ClientID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_JobRef As String
    Public Property JobRef() As String
        Get
            Return m_JobRef
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_JobRef = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_JobTitle As String
    Public Property JobTitle() As String
        Get
            Return m_JobTitle
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_JobTitle = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Location As String
    Public Property Location() As String
        Get
            Return m_Location
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Location = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_JobType As String
    Public Property JobType() As String
        Get
            Return m_JobType
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_JobType = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Salary As String
    Public Property Salary() As String
        Get
            Return m_Salary
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Salary = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_SalaryTerm As String
    Public Property SalaryTerm() As String
        Get
            Return m_SalaryTerm
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_SalaryTerm = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_BriefDescription As String
    Public Property BriefDescription() As String
        Get
            Return m_BriefDescription
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_BriefDescription = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_MoreDetails As String
    Public Property MoreDetails() As String
        Get
            Return m_MoreDetails
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_MoreDetails = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_DetailsDocument As String
    Public Property DetailsDocument() As String
        Get
            Return m_DetailsDocument
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_DetailsDocument = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_ClosingDate As DateTime
    Public Property ClosingDate() As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_ClosingDate
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            m_ClosingDate = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_CompanyName As String
    Public Property CompanyName() As String
        Get
            Return m_CompanyName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_CompanyName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' User for HTML
    Public Property HTMLData() As String
        Get
            Return m_Data
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Data = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Data As String
End Class
Public Class JobBoard
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String

    Public Property WSID() As String
        Get
            Return m_WSID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_WSID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_WSID As String

    Public Property JobDetails() As List(Of JobData)
        Get
            Return m_JobDetails
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of JobData))
            m_JobDetails = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_JobDetails As List(Of JobData)
End Class



Public Shared Function getJobsForWSID(ByVal wsid As String, ByRef mj As JobBoard) As JobBoard
    Dim mysql As String = RWP.OtherFormats.masterSelect(wsid).ToString.Trim
   ' HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(mysql) : HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
    Dim Conn As New MySqlConnection(dbconn)
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(mysql, Conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Conn.Open()
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim mytask As DataRow() = dt.[Select]
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In mytask

             ' THIS LINE CAUSES THE ERROR
             mj.JobDetails.Add(New JobData() With {.ID = dr("id"), .MAID = dr("master_agency_id"), .DateAdded = dr("date_added"), .ClientID = dr("client_id"), .JobRef = ts(dr("job_ref")), .JobTitle = ts(dr("job_title")), .Location = ts(dr("location")), .JobType = ts(dr("job_type")), .Salary = ts(dr("salary")), .SalaryTerm = ts(dr("salary_term")), .BriefDescription = ts(dr("brief_desc")), .MoreDetails = ts(dr("more_details")), .DetailsDocument = ts(dr("details_document")), .ClosingDate = dr("closing_date"), .CompanyName = dr("company_name")})

        Next
    End If
    da = Nothing
    Conn.Close()
    Conn.Dispose()
    Conn = Nothing
    dt = Nothing

    Return mj

End Function
```

This is the compiler output:-

```
D:\inetpub\vhosts\api.rankcareers.co.uk\httpdocs\App_Code\acesapiws1.vb(254) : error BC30068: Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.

    mj.JobDetails.Add(New JobData() With {.ID = dr("id"), .MAID = dr("master_agency_id"), .DateAdded = dr("date_added"), .ClientID = dr("client_id"), .JobRef = ts(dr("job_ref")), .JobTitle = ts(dr("job_title")), .Location = ts(dr("location")), .JobType = ts(dr("job_type")), .Salary = ts(dr("salary")), .SalaryTerm = ts(dr("salary_term")), .BriefDescription = ts(dr("brief_desc")), .MoreDetails = ts(dr("more_details")), .DetailsDocument = ts(dr("details_document")), .ClosingDate = dr("closing_date"), .CompanyName = dr("company_name")})
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
D:\inetpub\vhosts\api.rankcareers.co.uk\httpdocs\App_Code\acesapiws1.vb(254) : error BC32017: Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

    mj.JobDetails.Add(New JobData() With {.ID = dr("id"), .MAID = dr("master_agency_id"), .DateAdded = dr("date_added"), .ClientID = dr("client_id"), .JobRef = ts(dr("job_ref")), .JobTitle = ts(dr("job_title")), .Location = ts(dr("location")), .JobType = ts(dr("job_type")), .Salary = ts(dr("salary")), .SalaryTerm = ts(dr("salary_term")), .BriefDescription = ts(dr("brief_desc")), .MoreDetails = ts(dr("more_details")), .DetailsDocument = ts(dr("details_document")), .ClosingDate = dr("closing_date"), .CompanyName = dr("company_name")})
```

Can anyone suggest why this would be?

Comment: Not [tag:asp-classic] with you originally used [tag:asp] don't as it is a synonym of [tag:asp-classic] and not related to [tag:asp.net]. The two are completely different animals.

Comment: I have now managed to resolve the issue.  I rewrote the code to output the XML from a Dataset.